# Data Processing between user control and pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Dear Expert I have On user Control named as Uc1.axcs  one property Named as

```
   public string ExamApp1
    {
        get { return txtExamAppeared1.Text; }
    }
```

and i had used to it another user control uc2.axcs

and then after i had used the uc2.axcs user control in the page test.aspx
My question is that i want to use the ExamApp1 in the page test.aspx how can i do that without 
Find Control property is their any way to retun Uc1 usercontrol from uc2 through property and 
and used the ExamApp1 property through that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to expose that through a method in `uc2`:

```
public string GetExamApp1()
{
    return uc1Instance.ExamApp1;
}
```

Where `uc1Instance` is the id used for your `uc1` control instance in your `uc2` control.

Comment: Yes i can do like that but uc1 more than 14 properties then i have to create the property in cu2 also in uc2 i have used to more than 5 control then i have to create for all

Comment: OK then you create just one method through which you publish the instance of `uc1` to the world: `public uc1 GetUC1 { return uc1Instance; }`. Now you can navigate from your page all the way down to the properties of `uc1`.

Comment: @CyberDude do you know anywhere I could read more on exposing the entire control?. Instead of exposing individual properties..

Comment: @michaelhanon how about if you just return the control instance itself instead of only one property? You will still only have access to the public properties of it anyway, so you might still have to expose some of them through such public methods.